# css Flexbox - set flex: 1 1 150px; but the item isn't growing or shrinking as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<form id="contact-form" method="get" action="/~18xx15/a5/recipe/pizza-dough.php">
    <div class="row">
        <label for="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_NAME ?>">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_NAME ?>" id="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_NAME ?>" maxlength="100"/> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label for="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_TEXT ?>">Comment (Required):</label>
        <textarea name="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_TEXT ?>" id="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_TEXT ?>" rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post" disabled/>         
</form>
```

The goal is ***"The form labels have a basis/minimum width of 150px and a maximum width of 200px at screen sizes of 768px and more."***

This is what I have in my responsive.css. However, when the screen size is 768px or larger, my labels won't shirnk or grow. They just stay at 200px. How can I fix it?

```
form .row {
    display: flex;
}
form .row label {
    flex:1 1 150px;
    max-width:200px;
}
form .row input, form .row textarea {   
    flex:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply your responsive styles at screen size 768px, please using CSS Media Query.
For your case, I can modify your styles to:

```css
form .row {
  display: flex;
}

form .row label {
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

form .row input,
form .row textarea {
  flex: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  form .row label {
    flex-basis: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
 <form
      id="contact-form"
      method="get"
      action="/~18xx15/a5/recipe/pizza-dough.php"
    >
      <div class="row">
        <label for="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_NAME ?>">Name:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_NAME ?>"
          id="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_NAME ?>"
          maxlength="100"
        />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_TEXT ?>">Comment (Required):</label>
        <textarea
          name="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_TEXT ?>"
          id="<?= USER_COMMENT_FORM_TEXT ?>"
          rows="5"
          required
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="Post" disabled />
    </form>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that these css are already in Media Query. The problem is the flexbox that the label wont grow or shrink

Comment: You can't using property with different value for one selector (`flex:1 1 150px` and `max-width:200px`). In the end only one value will be used.